# PHP MySql Query performance with variable declaration

Tags: php, mysql

Alright - this may be a dumb question, but my desire for perfection is fueling me, so, if it is stupid and pointless, just let me know.

I have a mysql query where I fetch rows from a database table, and I need the value in some shape or form for all the columns I collect.  Look at the following sample code (this could use an array to gather output instead - the fundamental question should be the same):

```
$query="SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table1 WHERE 'X'='Y'";
$result=mysql_query($query,$resource);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $var1=$row['A'];   $var2=$row['B'];

   echo '<li class="' . $row['C'] . '" id="' . $row['D'] . '">';
}
```

My question is as follows:

I only need $row['A'] and $row['B'] once since they are the same value for every row in this case, but I do need them once.  The other values will be different for every row, and I need them as well, as in the example.

Is there a problem with continuously setting the variable throughout the loop?  Or is it better to use `if(!isset`...? or is there some other way to do this?  Or is the performance hit so minimal as to make this question irrelevant?

Thanks

Comment: How would you use `if (!isset(` exactly?

Comment: If (!isset($var1)){ $var1=$row['A'];}

Comment: Why was this downvoted and why was it edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just set the variables outside the loop.

```
$result=mysql_query($query,$resource);
$result_new = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$var1 = $result_new['A']; //considering $result_new['A'] always exists 
$var2=$result_new['B']; //considering $result_new['B'] always exists
while($row=$result_new){ 
echo '<li class="' . $row['C'] . '" id="' . $row['D'] . '">';
}
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it gave a clear scientific demonstration of the results  that I  was looking for.  Your answer was the best techinque-wise - because it was this sort of obvious (we are all blind to what is right in front of our face) sort of answer that I was looking for.  Were I able to accept two, I would.  I upvoted it though.

Comment: ooh, thts k, i dint see that u accepted an answere already :)

Answer (score 1):

Really don't bother with that. Unless you're looping over millions of records.

If you need more speed, don't echo in the while loop:

```
 $result=mysql_query($query,$resource);
    $string ='';
if ($result) {
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$string .= '<li class="' . $row['C'] . '" id="' . $row['D'] . '">';
$var1=$row['A'];
$var2=$row['B'];

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $var1=$row['A']; $var2=$row['B'];
    $string .= '<li class="' . $row['C'] . '" id="' . $row['D'] . '">';
    }
   }
    echo $string;
```

Two more things. Don't use mysql_*: Use of this extension is discouraged!

And (like I thought someone else said) if a/b is always the same, you should rethink you're database structure.

Edit:
To give a real answer to your question:
I did a small test. 
Setting the value on each loop (1,000 times) takes 0.00027s. Checking inside the loop if the value was already set takes 0.00030s. So just setting it each time is even faster than checking.

Comment: maybe A and B are only the same for this `WHERE` filter ;) - but otherwise, agreed

Comment: Yes but then he would have those variables already to make the WHERE so he wouldn't need them in this loop...

Comment: Thanks -> That is a cool test.  That is the crux of the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Also.  I think the problem is not with the database, but rather with the front-end code that needs these results.  I think it actually doesn't need the results that are the same, but I got them because I kept getting confused with a hierarchial database call.

Answer (score 1):

1. the performance hit in this scenario is irrelevant, in fact i would speculate if `if(isset..)` guards would take a tiny bit longer - only scenario I can think of, where this question would matter would be a situation where you assign (larger) objects or arrays to `$var1` and somehow force php to make a copy, not a reference
2. if it bothers you for aesthetic reasons (I could relate ;)), you could use a do - while loop:

   ```
   //assuming you always get at least one result
   $result=mysql_query($query,$resource);
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $var1=$row['A'];   $var2=$row['B'];

   do {
     // the loop stuff - stringify or echo the list
   } while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ;
   ```

Comment: almost same as mine, but what if mysql returns an empty result set?

Comment: it's just a fast example to show the principle - that's why I put the comment in there ;). Sure, a real world application needs some error checking here...(ok, and I'm lazy and don't like to type much formatted code in stackoverflow)

Comment: i know, but everyone else are perfectionists ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a do-while expression

```
$query="SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table1 WHERE 'X'='Y'";
$result=mysql_query($query,$resource);
if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $var1=$row['A'];   $var2=$row['B'];
    do {
        echo '<li class="' . $row['C'] . '" id="' . $row['D'] . '">';
    } while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
}
```